# Selecting multiple images and adding it to canvas

Tags: android, android-image

I am trying to let user select multiple images and then load the selected images on a canvas.  Is there anyway to save the selected images on one canvas. If I use

```
  Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
            pickIntent.setType("image/*");
            pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, "Select Picture"), PICKER);
```

This will return all images but I want images in a specified folder 
Eg. String filepath = "/sdcard/MyFolder/";

Thanks,

Comment: `Is there anyway to save the selected images on one canvas` - yes.  What have you tried?

Comment: You would need to have a Custom View (or maybe an ImageView) and manually draw the images on the canvas using the onDraw() callback function.